# Concatenate all cells that match criteria (Excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a spreadsheet like the following:

[image: A bunch of pieces of text on top of each other. When a piece of text starts with 'fob', it is concatenated with all other cells in another cell]

The expected outcome is all cells starting with specific text concatenated in order with their number of appearance.

The formatting like in the image is not essential, but preferable. However, the number (1, 2, 3) in front of each part is quite important.

I've tried using SUMIF and CONCAT to refer to rainbow tables and multi-step processes, but they all ended up getting out of hand, slow and unreliable.

If possible, I'd like to do it without macros/UDFs, as my system administrator does not like them, but if there is no other way that is fine.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: So, if the first three letters of a cell are 'fob' you want to take the rest of the characters in that cell and concatenate them into a designated target location with no spaces between them? Is that what you want?

Comment: And could you [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1362963/edit) to let us know what you've tried so far?

Comment: Yes, with the order of appearance as shown in the image. So it wouldn't be "HelloWorldSuperuser", it would be something like '1. Hello2. World3.Superuser'.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad OK.

Comment: The main part is to selectively concatenate anything that matches specific conditions. The rest is just design and styling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest a solution based on little bit of VBA code and Excel 2016's TEXTJOIN function. Note that this will work in Excel 2016 and above, however will not work on lower versions. In that case you will have to create UDF for TEXTJOIN. I am referring to your tag Excel 2016.

In this example sample data is in cells E4:E15.

Press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> to open VBA Editor. Insert a Module from Insert Menu and put the following code into it.

```
Function GetString(a1 As String) As String

Dim array1 As Variant
Dim mystring As String

array1 = Split(a1, "|")

For i = LBound(array1) To UBound(array1)

    mystring = mystring & i + 1 & "." & array1(i) & " "

Next i

GetString = mystring

End Function
```

Save the Excel file as .XLSM Macro Enabled Excel Worksheet.

Now in F4 for example put the following formula and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to create and Array Formula. The formula shall be enclosed in Curly Braces to indicate that it's an Array Formula.

```
=GetString(TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,IF(LEFT(E4:E14,3)="fob",RIGHT(E4:E14,LEN(E4:E14)-LEN("fob")),"")))
```

Now you get your string as desired.

Limitation - Note that here I am using pipe character "|" as Delimiter. So in rare case if your Text itself has a pipe in it the results may not be as expected. In that case use one of those characters that can be obtained using ALT + number pad e.g. ALT + 789 e.g. §

[image]

---

In case you prefer pure Excel Formula Approach, I  suggest below solution based on a Helper Column.

In this example sample data is in cells B3:B13.
Now in C3 put the following formula and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to create an array formula. Now drag it down up to the intended rows.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$3:$B$13,SMALL(IF(LEFT($B$3:$B$13,3)="fob",ROW($B$3:$B$13)-2,""),ROW(A1))),"")
```

Note the -2 here. This is important, it sets the Index value to start with 1 based on the relative row in which your list starts.

This formula shall create a contagious list of required rows from your original column.

Now in D3 put the following formula and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> from within the formula bar to create an Array formula.

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(LEN(C3:C13)=0,"",ROW(C3:C13)-2&"."&RIGHT(C3:C13,LEN(C3:C13)-LEN("fob"))))
```

Now you should get your intended string in D3. See the below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go; however, I'm not sure if my school system allows macros

Comment: See my updated answer. If you are ok with a helper column you can opt for this solution in case Macros are not allowed.

Comment: Helper columns are fine; I'm using them already. Thanks ever so much!